# How do you add a list to a web part in Sharepoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have a web part in visual studio. The web part will contain 3 textboxes, 1 button and 1 list display.

What control do i use to display the custom list on the web part?

Comment: Please mention that what is the use of your webpart and what is its functionality. Then any one can explain in more detail.

Comment: the webpart will be a search control e.g. the user will enter data into textboxes and when they click search button this will update the custom list that is displayed.

Comment: Are you filtering the results from the only particular list? Do the solution as said in my answer.

Comment: Is SPQuery the best way to filter the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to display the list in your webpart you can do it form the editing the page where you want to add your web part and add from the list & libraries section of available webparts.
If you want your text boxes and button and list to display on your webpart then you can do the following.

1. Take a visual webpart in visual studio (deploy it as a farm solution).
2. add your controls over there. If you want to display list, you can show them in a grid control.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Mihir. Can i chat with you on skype, i need some help with starting sharepoint development.

Comment: I dont have skype access. You can use the SPQuery to get the data from a list or across the lists. Use SPGrid to show the results. That won't be difficult. :)

Comment: Thanks Mihir. Your a life saver